# What are some examples of "checks and balances" outside of the United States?

Tags: checks-and-balances, judiciary, executive

The three branches of the United States government (legislative, executive, and judicial) all participate in the governing process and in many cases can *check* the actions of another branch.  Are there other systems of checks and balances that prevent a part of a government from overstepping its bounds, and is different from the kind that the US uses?

Comment: I think this question needs to be made more specific. "Checks and balances" for what - powers to arrest, powers to cease property? Other kinds of separation of power?

Comment: You are asking for a List Of Things. That is not very constructive.

Comment: @Casebash I think that depends on what the government in question has the authority to do. If the government doesn't have the authority to arrest, does a part of that government check to make sure that it doesn't occur?
The focus of the question is about what other methods governments use to police themselves and make sure they do (only) what they are _supposed_ to.